# Random errors when changing series using JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jfreechart

I'm making a GUI that display result of background calculations. But before that, I wanted to test changing the dataset. Here is my code:

```
 DefaultXYDataset dataset = new DefaultXYDataset();
@Override
        public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for (int i = 0; i < periods; i++) {
                        series[0][i] = (double) i;
                        series[1][i] = 0;
                }
                dataset.addSeries("Series0", series);
                for (int it = 0; it < 10; it++) {
                        series[1][random.nextInt(periods)] =  random.nextInt(100) / 2;
                        double[][] d = new double[2][periods];
                        for (int i = 0; i < periods; i++) {
                                d[0][i] = series[0][i];
                                d[1][i] = series[1][i];
                        }
                        dataset.removeSeries("Series0");
                        dataset.addSeries("Series0", series);
//                      try {
//                              Thread.sleep(100);
//                      } catch (java.lang.InterruptedException ex) {
//                      }
                }
```

As you can see, I want to change points on the graph (every time it finishes 'some complicated computations') - this change is in the thread invoked by me in another class. My problem is that this whole concept is not working. It throws 'Series index out of bounds'-IllegalArgumentException, 'index out of bounds' - of some library inner arraylist etc.. I'm not using DynamicTimeSeriesCollection because I need the X axis to be the number of my inner iterations not the time period, and also update when 'some computations' are finished not every some time period. Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or is there a better way to update/refresh the graph?

Comment: You need to post pertinent code here with your question. Best would be as close to an [sscce](http://sscce.org) as you could get.

Comment: I'm not sure if this changes anything, because imo the problem is with the code I've supplied. But as long as you're willing to help me, this is full code:http://pastebin.com/zEBHZYj4 . This class is added to some JPanel, I'm invoking new Thread(JPaintablePanel).start(); with a button

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your snippet is incorrectly synchronized; you should update your `dataset` from the `process()` method of a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513). Because your domain is "the number of my inner iterations", don't use a `DateAxis`; instead, use a `NumberAxis`, as shown in [`ChartFactory.createXYLineChart()`](https://github.com/jfree/jfreechart/blob/c1a6c13526273a319319d2dc8979e5b5b2c97531/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/ChartFactory.java#L1527).

Addendum: This variation on the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) plots the worker's progress on a line chart. Note that `createXYLineChart()` uses `NumberAxis` for both domain and range. Given a `series` in the line chart's dataset, note also how the implementation of `process()` can safely update the dataset as new data arrives; the listening chart will update itself in response.

```
private XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Result");
…
@Override
protected void process(List<Double> chunks) {
    for (double d : chunks) {
        label.setText(df.format(d));
        series.add(++n, d);
    }
}
```

[image: chart]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartFactory;
import org.jfree.chart.ChartPanel;
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.axis.NumberAxis;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYLineAndShapeRenderer;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637215
 */
public final class ChartWorker {

    private static final String S = "0.000000000000000";
    private final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    private final JLabel label = new JLabel(S, JLabel.CENTER);
    private final XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Result");
    private final XYDataset dataset = new XYSeriesCollection(series);

    private void create() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("√2");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(progressBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
            "Newton's Method", "X", "Y", dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
        XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
        plot.getRangeAxis().setRange(1.4, 1.51);
        plot.getDomainAxis().setStandardTickUnits(
            NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
        XYLineAndShapeRenderer renderer
            = (XYLineAndShapeRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
        renderer.setSeriesShapesVisible(0, true);
        f.add(new ChartPanel(chart) {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                return new Dimension(640, 480);
            }
        }, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        f.add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        runCalc();
    }

    private void runCalc() {
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        TwoWorker task = new TwoWorker();
        task.addPropertyChangeListener((PropertyChangeEvent e) -> {
            if ("progress".equals(e.getPropertyName())) {
                progressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
                progressBar.setValue((Integer) e.getNewValue());
            }
        });
        task.execute();
    }

    private class TwoWorker extends SwingWorker<Double, Double> {

        private static final int N = 5;
        private final DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(S);
        double x = 1;
        private int n;

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground() throws Exception {
            for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
                x = x - (((x * x - 2) / (2 * x)));
                setProgress(i * (100 / N));
                publish(x);
                Thread.sleep(1000); // simulate latency
            }
            return x;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<Double> chunks) {
            for (double d : chunks) {
                label.setText(df.format(d));
                series.add(++n, d);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new ChartWorker()::create);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for swingworker i'll try it! But can you expand Number/DateAxs idea? where is it shown and what should I change?

Comment: @aragornsql: I've elaborated above.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have another maybe not related question. I have to ChartPanel in cardLayout to switch between the graphs when I click on tabbed pane. I've tried it with ordinary JPanel("public class JPaintablePanel extends JPanel" -it showing some button with different name depending on the tab), and it works well. But the same thing with "public class JPaintablePanel extends ChartPanel" is not working, it shows only one graph. Can you tell me how to force ChartPanell to switch, and preserve data? http://pastebin.com/THuvGan5 ChartPanel, http://pastebin.com/Br2swZiC cardLayout

Comment: Marked as accepted. Next question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13208626/cardlayout-with-jfreechard-switching-is-not-working