# Initialize JFreeChart range axis values

Tags: jfreechart

I am trying to load dataset during initialization of the JFreeChart. But every time I tried to create a dataset with higher "number of item per series", the more data (all data) displayed visible in the chart (the bigger the dataset, the smaller the graph). But actually what I wanted is to have the fixed range of dataset values displayed on the chart while the rest is still hidden. Just the same way the data would normally be displayed in the actual trading platform, let's say Metatrader (MT4). First time when I open the chart I can see the screen filled with the only visible dataset of the chart and if I left-scroll the chart I will be able to see the old/history dataset as well. Does anyone have idea how to achieve this using JFreechart?

Really appreciate for any help or any thing/articles I can refer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setRange()` on either the domain or range axis, as shown in this [fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513). If you've already tried this, it may help to edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) and/or image that exhibits any problems you encountered.