# JFreeChart - Display x Axis without range

Tags: java, jfreechart

Given I have the following serie:

```
    series1.add(3, 0);
    series1.add(6, 0);
    series1.add(13, 0);
    series1.add(34, 0);
    series1.add(49, 1.0);
    series1.add(51, 0);
    series1.add(54, 0);
    series1.add(55, 0);
    series1.add(60, 0);
    series1.add(89, 0);
    series1.add(108, 0);
    series1.add(208, 0);
    series1.add(228, 0);
```

For X values I would like to not use any interval (range) for these values. In resume, I like to display, for x-axis exactly the values listed on series 1.

This is possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13217658/230513).

Comment: @elf: Just a heads-up that people will stop trying to answer your questions if you don't accept some of them - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686755/meaning-of-epsilon-argument-of-assertequals-for-double-values in particular really deserves an accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the setRange method.

xAxis.setRange(min, max);

In your case the min is 3 and the max is 228. Simply use the method (xAxis.setRange(3, 228);) and your problem is solved.