# Where should I invoke my swingworker in a Java MVC pattern

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, swingworker

I have a program that is basically set up just like the one in this MVC example: http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html

In my program there is a process which takes quite a bit of time which freezes my GUI. I want to GUI to continuously update while the process is running. To do this I believe I need to use a SwingWorker. I don't know where in my MVC pattern I should be invoking this SwingWorker.

My thinking is that I should be running it in the MultiplyListener actionlistener of the controller. Would this be correct?

Comment: afaics, that link doesn't describe MVC: it's missing the model's responsibility of notifying on changes - or what am I missing?

Comment: @kleopatra: Good comment; I've tried to elaborate below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the *model* is a mathematical operation that evolves over time, perhaps by iteration. Clearly, the worker belongs in the model, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513).  The `setProgress()` method will notify any `PropertyChangeListener`, and `process()` can notify any other listening *view*, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).

Addendum: In the second [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513), the worker updates a different *model*: the chart's dataset named `collection`. The chart, in turn, listens to the dataset and updates itself in response to the change.

In the [example cited](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html), the *controller* installs action listeners on behalf of the *model* and *view*. In this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513), the GUI action listeners are local to their respective *views*. In either case, [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) would be a suitable choice for encapsulation. The *model* notifies its observers when its internal state changes in response to user initiated actions.

Comment: The [example cited](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/GUI/structure/40mvc.html) seems more traditional, while Swing is more _model_-centric. Conceptually, I think of the user as the GUI controller.

Answer (score 2):

I think that your `SwingWorker` belongs in the *Control* and I'll tell you why. I feel that the *Model* should be as *View* agnostic as possible and should be created with the idea that it can be used with different views and controls, and even with a completely different GUI library, if desired. For instance, you are currently wanting to use the *Model* in a Swing GUI, but what if later you want to use it in an Android application? In order to allow it to be used with as few modifications as possible, most code that is Swing-specific, such as a `SwingWorker` should reside in the *Control* or *View*.

For example, please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15729267/522444).

Comment: I agree that the model should be as view agnostic as possible.  I'm curious though--would you offer the same advice of using the controller for encapsulating the long-running process if that process were not specifically a `SwingWorker`, but were instead inheriting from `Thread`?  My understanding was that `SwingWorker` was a convenience class very tightly integrated with `Swing`. If he were instead building such a construct himself which weren't so tightly integrated with `Swing` specifically, he might consider storing it elsewhere (the model), right?