# Use SwingWorker to initialize a JFrame I want to return

Tags: java, swing, jframe, swingworker

I have a simple static method that, when given a list of numbers has to create a `JFrame` holding a histogram.

I use a `SwingWorker` (the `doInBackground()` does the number crunching, the done() creates the frame and the `ChartPanel`).

Now I'd like to return a reference (or a Future) of the JFrame created in `done()` to whoever calls this static method. Is there a way to do so?
I am saying returning a Future because obviously the JFrame only exists after the `done()` method is done.

Comment: You can use get() to retrieve the return value of your doInBackground() mehtod. I can´t tell you if it will work with a Future, never tried anything similar.

Comment: SwingWorker isn't to designated for creating a Swing Objects (event is possible, bunch of code examples here that contains), create this Object off_screen, place there JComponents, layout JComponents (doesn't matter on apps start), call pack() and setVisible() in done() wrappped into invokeLater

Comment: expl. - > SwingWorker is only the bridge betweens Workers Threads and Swing Objects, from methods publish(), proccess(), setProcess() and done() guarantee that output will be notified EDT

Comment: @mrKorbel I am not sure I understood the comment. Of course JFrame/JComponents constructors can only be called in EDT(AT ALL TIMES: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t707173-why-does-jdk-1-6-recommend-creating-swing-components-on-the-edt.html ). Even if I don't use SwingWorker and rather use invokeLater I still can't return the JFrame reference since it will only be filled in on a different thread. I am asking how to build a Future to reference a newly created Jframe when it's going to be created on EDT (SwingWorker or the invokeLater, doesn't matter)

Comment: @jannis-alexakis thanks, but get() returns the results of doInBackground() not so much the "results" of done()

Comment: See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: The question wouldn't change if you were to substitute JFrame with JPanel, but thank you for the link. Very interesting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to waiting for `done()`, create your frame and chart panel on the EDT, `publish()` interim results and update your chart's dataset in `process()`. As shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513), the chart listens to changes in the dataset and should update automatically.