# JFreeChart does not show the graph at every iteration on thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, graph, jfreechart

I am getting counter values in one class using a thread and writing `JFreeChart` in another thread. While executing, it works alternatively, but only shows the graph at the end. It also displays the y axis label value as a Float but the actual retrieval value is int. How can I solve these issues?

```
        XYDataset Dataset;
        TimeSeries Series = new TimeSeries("Random Data");
        Second sec = new Second();
        ChartPanel CPanel;
        Value = Integer.parseInt(MySQLClass.Map_MySql.get(""+MainWindow.SelectedNode+""));

        String CounterName = MainWindow.SelectedNode.toString();
        Series.add(sec, Value);
        Dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection(Series);
        System.out.println("Ds="+Dataset);
        Chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(CounterName, "Time", "Range", Dataset, true, false, false);
        System.out.println("Chart Created");
        XYPlot Plot = (XYPlot)Chart.getPlot();
        Plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        Plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.WHITE);
        Plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.RED);
        Panel1.revalidate();
        CPanel = new ChartPanel(Chart);
        CPanel.setVisible(true);
        Panel1.add(CPanel);
        System.out.println("Chart Added");
        Panel1.validate();

        Thread.sleep((int)MainWindow.Interval_Combo.getSelectedItem() * 1000);
        System.gc();
```

This thread for accessing those two class

```
        while(true)
        {
            MySQLClass m = new MySQLClass();
            Thread t1 = new Thread(m);
            t1.start();
            t1.join();
            Graph g = new Graph();
            Thread t2 = new Thread(g);
            t2.start();
            t2.join();
        }
```

In MySql class, i hust get the counter name and value and store it in Hashmap called Map_Mysql in followiung manner.

```
   while(rs.next())
   {
     Map_MySql.put(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2));
   }
```

I dont know what the actual problem, please solve this. Output look like,

**MySql Occur

com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@2c8ab0

Graph Occur

42913

Ds=org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection@c204e809

MySql Occur

com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection@1930b4b

Graph Occur

44217**

At the end show the graph with float value in Y axis for last value with no graphical representation.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which we can use to reproduce your problems.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't* sleep on the [event dispatch thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). As shown in [*Concurrency in Swing*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), use a worker thread to update the dataset on the EDT in `process()`. A complete example is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).

Comment: SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new MySQLClass()); SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Graph()); I am calling those two threads like this. It will also work alternatively but produce result at the end. The Panel is not visible from the starting. please help me. I am stucking here. Is there any fault in my code???

Comment: Showing results at the end a classic symptom of blocking the EDT with `sleep()`. I strongly recommend a `SwingWorker` to run the query. Does the example cited not work for you?

Answer (score 1):

For your second question (integer axis labels instead of float), this can be handled by calling the [setStandardTickUnits()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setStandardTickUnits%28org.jfree.chart.axis.TickUnitSource%29) method on the axis.  You can pass any [TickUnitSource](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/TickUnitSource.html), but easiest for you is probably [NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits()](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/NumberAxis.html#createIntegerTickUnits%28%29).

Comment: NumberAxis NAxis = (NumberAxis)Plot.getRangeAxis();   NAxis.setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());               if i use this, the graph shows one current value in Y axis not any nearby values....