# JFreeChart Java - How to create it is a lot of series in a cycle

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart

I have a spline graphic that get coordinates from InitP file. I plan to expand a code to make loading of graphics of several files (for each graphic there is the file with a set of coordinates).

On an input the line with names of files. In a cycle in each series for dataset coordinates for the appropriate diagram will be skidded. Difficulty arises in creation of new series, I don't know as to create a new series when reading the new file (I don't know how to create series2, series3 in cycle because I dont know how many series will be). There is a code for one graphic.

```
        series1 = new XYSeries("Graph");
        try {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("InitP"));
                System.out.println("Open success!");
                float xpol =  0, ypol = 0;
                s.useLocale(Locale.US);
                while (s.hasNext()) {
                    if (s.hasNextFloat()) {
                        xpol = s.nextFloat();
                        ypol = s.nextFloat();
                        System.out.println("x = " + xpol + ", y = " + ypol);
                        series1.add(xpol, ypol);

                    } else {
                        s.next();
                    }
                }
                dataset.addSeries(series1);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                System.out.println("Can't find file!");
            }
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your `XYSeriesCollection dataset` *before* looping through the files. For each file, create a new `XYSeries` and use `dataset.addSeries()` to add the new series to the existing `dataset`. The listening chart will update itself, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522583/230513). Because file access is inherently asynchronous, loop through the files in your implementation of the `doInBackground()` method of a `SwingWorker`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).

Addendum: *I need to create `seriesN`, where `N` is a digit.*

As a concrete example, the `createDataset()` method below adds a series for each file in `"user.dir"`. It uses the file's `hashcode()` for numbering, but you can increment a counter, etc.

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import org.jfree.chart.*;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.PlotOrientation;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeries;
import org.jfree.data.xy.XYSeriesCollection;

/** @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21953170/230513 */
public class ChartPanelXYTest {

    private static final Random random = new Random();

    private static XYDataset createDataset() {
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        File[] files = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            XYSeries series = new XYSeries("f" + f.hashCode());
            for (int i = 0; i < f.getName().length(); i++) {
                series.add(i, random.nextGaussian());
            }
            dataset.addSeries(series);
        }
        return dataset;
    }

    private static JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart("Test", "Domain",
            "Range", dataset, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, false, false);
        return chart;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame();
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                XYDataset dataset = createDataset();
                JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
                ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart) {
                    @Override
                    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                        return new Dimension(640, 480);
                    }
                };
                f.add(chartPanel);
                f.pack();
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but how create new **XYSeries** in the loop? I don't understand this step. I need to create seriesN, where N is a digit. How to make it in loop? And thanks for **doInBackground()**, I forgot about it

Comment: I'm not sure where you're stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You might use the following strategy:

- Outer loop: read a file (or process input arguments) to get the names of each separate file of coordinates
- For each file name, create a Series and add it to a Vector
- Process the series from the file name (don't forget to close each file when you have finished)
- Cycle