# create a graph from result of bubblesort

Tags: java, swing, sorting, graph, bubble-sort

I have a GUI with a button and check boxes, when button clicked it calls a method that gets an amount "10000+" numbers from a CSV file and bubblesorts them, it also checks the comparisons too. My question is how can I create a graph to show my results, not in excel looking to do on the `JFrame` or open a new `JFrame` when sort has completed. Not sure how to go about it, are there any plugins for eclipse or libraries I can use. Can you provide me with tutorials or links to some useful sites that might help. thanks in advance

Comment: You could take a look at [JFreeCharts](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Comment: It's not clear what the "results" are, and how they should be shown. Do you want a bar chart showing the sorted numbers? This will be difficult for more than 1000 numbers. Or do you somehow want to visualize the number of comparisons?

Comment: will do now MadProgrammer thanks

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).

Comment: @Marco what happens is I actually have a CSV file with 1 million random numbers I read them into an arraylist and then select an amount to sort record the time and comparison made, the use can enter the start range, increments and end. Eg: Start with 1000 record, increment by 500, and end at 10,000 or so recording how long each increment took. Hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: @trashgod ye that looks like what I need.