# Create a discontinue trace in JChart2D

Tags: java, swing, charts, jchart2d

I am using Trace2DLtd, and I have 300 data points per trace, as it is real time, once it reaches x=300 I start writing back again at x=0, but when going back from 300 to 0 a line crosses the graph and I haven’t being able to create a discontinuity or something similar to avoid having that line across the graph. How can this be done without erasing the whole dataset?

Comment: The line probably connects your last datum at `x = 300` to your next at `x = 0`. Can you add a datum that coincides with the axis? An alternative using [tag:jfreechart] is shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5048852/230513).

Comment: Thanks trashgod. I already tried adding it, but as I have multiple traces per graph, and I have zooming and offset options this didn't worked that well. I have also tried jfreechart and I was able to do it over there, unfortunately I had to move away from jfreechart because my application handles a large amount of data in real time and JFreeChart was to heavy to be able to handle it.

Comment: I'm usually able to collect in real time and update reasonably promptly in a `SwingWorker`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).

Comment: I have two swingworkers, one for plotting and another one for communication. When I start adding series in jfreechart it starts affecting my communication worker. I can have up to 4 series without a problem but more than that start affecting communication. with JChart2D I was able to go up to 16, that is why I have to move from JFreeChart. Perhaps the amount of data required to be updated is too large for JFreeChart (at least 1600 datapoints every 100 ms)