# JPanel transition and calculation in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have a Swing application, in which initial JFrame (`frame`) has one JPanel (`firstPanel`) with one button. On clicking this button, the JFrame should remove `firstPanel` and add a new JPanel (`secondPanel`). There is one simple JLabel (`lab`) in secondPanel, whose text will be based on some calculation which might take some time.

Right now, `secondPanel` gets initialized only after the calculation is completed. I want to initialize `secondPanel` with empty label initially. Calculation should be done in parallel and content of label should be changed when calculation is completed. How can I do this?

Comment: Use a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13205322/230513).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: reformatted grammar to make question easier to read, fixed typo in title